# Disable textbox and select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several textboxes that disables the submit button unless they are all filled up. I have also a dropdwon list but won't disable the submit button until the user have chosen. How can I disable the submit button until all fields are filled and satisfied? pls help

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function success() {
      if (document.getElementById("uname").value === "" || document.getElementById("age").value === "" || document.getElementById("sex").selectValue == "Please Select") {
        document.getElementById('submit_form').disabled = true;

      } else {
        document.getElementById('submit_form').disabled = false;
      }
    }
  </script>

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Name: <input type="text" id="uname" onkeyup="success()"/> Age: <input type="text" id="age" onkeyup="success()"/> Sex:
  <select id="sex" name="sex">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> Please Select </option>
  <option value="Male"> Male </option>
  <option value="Female"> Female </option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_form" value="Submit" disabled>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're calling `disable()` when you only have `success()` function, also unnecessary `/` on <select.... />

Comment: I updated my code. Pls see

Comment: I need the submit button disabled until all fields are filled in by the user

Comment: Not working. Submit button remained disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (
   document.getElementById("uname").value == "" ||
   document.getElementById("age").value == "" ||
   document.getElementById("sex").value == ""
  ) {
   document.getElementById("submit_form").disabled = true;
  } else {
   document.getElementById("submit_form").disabled = false;
  }
});
```

Here is pen: https://codepen.io/ahmetzeybek/pen/ROqLme

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use "prop" function to disable select box:

```
<script>
$('#select_id').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>
```

And to disable text box you could just add "readonly" attribute to the element, using jquery:

```
<script>
 $("#textboxid").attr("readonly");
</script>
```